# android listview and button and text with gesture detection

Tags: android, listview, button, gestures

I am new to android programming. I have this problem that I created a listView with button and text. I wanted all of this object to be active. Meaning I can click or touch any of these 3. The main idea is, I will display a listview of products. When I select a list it will bring me to a details view. And when I click a button it will add the current selection + 1 to the current textbox. I also want the textbox to be editable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my [WaddleAddressBook](https://bitbucket.org/atgheb/waddleaddressbook/src/d243c537d801/src/com/waddleworks/addressbook?at=master)

The `EfficientAdapter` has code on how to implement each item.
The `WaddleAddressBook` shows an example of detecting gestures (swipe left and right in this case).

`search.xml` is the list item layout.

Each list item basically had a contact picture, contact name and 3 buttons under the contact name for call, sms and edit. You could swipe right to call and left to sms just like on Samsung phones... I never ended up finishing the address book but I hope it helps you.